# Set domain name to be related to a project in Wakatime

Tags: wakatime

How do I associate domains in Chrome to a specific project? Is it somehow supposed to be added to the .wakatime-project file in my coding directory?

This is what I see when I open up the wakatime options in chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Custom Rules" under "Settings".

1. Add rules filtering by `URL`, `contains`, `<domain-name>`
2. Set `Project` to `<project-name>`.
3. Save/Apply.